# Can I get the "symbol resolved" AST of the body of a live Python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given that I have a Python 3 function like:

```
def foo(x: int) -> int:
    y: int = x * x + 3
    return x + y
```

and from a different module I have access to the `foo` function, is it possible for me to get the annotated AST of `foo`?

I have a couple things I'd like to do that I think an annotated "symbol resolved" tree could really help me with:

1. Experiment with various kinds of code analysis. E.g. try to deduce return type of the function. Or runtime complexity of a function given the runtime complexity of the functions that it uses. Or even whether the function is referentially transparent. etc.
2. Translate an annotated subset of Python into different languages. For instance, the above function `foo` has a very natural translation to C. It isn't perfect (e.g. Python int has many properties that are very different from C int), but I'd like to experiment and see how far I can push it and see if there's room for interesting applications.

---

```
int foo(int x) {
  int y = x * x + 3;
  return x + y;
}
```

---

NOTE: I could be wrong, but for both of the applications above, I don't think simply parsing the raw function would get me everything I need. If the function I'm trying to use uses a function whose name is not in the parsing scope, I'm going to be stuck. I need the "Name" nodes to be annotated with either the first assignment in the block, or a reference to the scope that this function is closing over so I can access the value being referenced directly. At least in this way I can inspect the value being used for more sophisticated analysis.

Comment: Is `ast.parse()` not enough? It can return nodes of type `AnnAssign` that include the type annotation.

Comment: @kichik Maybe 'annotated' wasn't the best word for it... by annotated, I mean, symbol resolution. That is, given the name of a variable in the AST, what variable is it referring to? As I mention in the NOTE, if a function uses a non-local variable, a simple `ast.parse` wouldn't give me enough information.

Comment: maybe take a look at jedi? it's already doing a lot of this, but without needing the annotations (deducing return types, etc)... maybe you could use or build on what they have...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Ah cool thanks, it looks promising, I'll check that out!

Comment: Sounds like you may need to parse all the source code including libraries

Comment: @kichik that is true... `jedi` doesn't fit perfectly. Ideally I would like to extract the information from what's available at runtime. But I'm really glad I learned about it though.

Comment: if you want something at runtime, maybe more look at something like `line_profiler` and use the profiler hooks on top of jedi.... ....